# Email that allows auto responses via subject line with attachments

Tags: email, attachment

i want to host a email client on my web server that allows messages to be processed via subject line, i looked into roundcube's autoreply but that was only a global message for all incoming emails, for example, if my customer emailed me with subject line HOSTING, it would be filtered and sent an auto response with an attached pdf file of our hosting plans

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use Gmail's filters to do this, as otherwise it would be quite complicated. I would forward all the mail to Gmail, and use Gmail's filters (and canned response lab feature) to respond with the PDF attachment.

Comment: gmail does not allow attachments in the canned messages

Comment: @FrankLy So how is it possible to save a draft (an email template) with an attachment and use it to resend it? I want to have a saved template with 2 attachments and same subject. Then, I want to use this and send it to different email addresses. Is there a way? Or at least a client that can be used for free on iphone?